# WhatsApp doesn’t show usernames on notifications

Tags: notifications, whatsapp.app

Today I updated to version 2.18.52 & I can’t see the names of the people who send me a message. The only thing I see is the WhatsApp logo and the word “message”.

[image: You can see an example right here...]

I can’t also see the status my friends posts, they all look black. I uninstalled the app, reset my phone & nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you’re not seeing the names of those users sending you WhatsApp messages is because you haven’t got previews enabled in your Notification settings.

To do this:

1. Go to Settings > Notifications
2. At the top tap on the Show Previews option
3. Now select the option you want generally across all your apps (i.e. Always, When Unlocked, or Never)
4. Now go back to the main Notifications screen
5. Swipe up until you see the WhatsApp option
6. Tap on WhatsApp
7. Now at the very bottom of your WhatsApp Notifications settings you’ll have options relating to Previews - set this to **Never** if you don't want the actual message included in the Preview
8. Exit Settings
9. Launch WhatsApp and within its Settings go to Notifications and enable Show Preview (this step in combination with choosing *Never* at Step 7 will enable the contact name to be displayed in the preview, but not the message itself)

**Note:** You can skip steps 2 to 4 if you only want to set Preview settings for WhatsApp.

Comment: This was the solution:

To turn on previews that display the contact name but not message:

Go to WhatsApp > Settings > Notifications > turn Show Preview on.
Go to iPhone Settings > Notifications > WhatsApp > Show Previews > Never.