# How do I hide names from incoming messages on whatsapp on my iphone5

Tags: iphone, notifications, privacy, whatsapp.app

I dont want the contact names to show on the notification but I stillwant the notification badge to show

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when it comes to WhatsApp there are two sets of Settings that can affect what, if anything, is previewed from your WhatsApp messages.

WhatsApp has its own settings:

1. Tap on WhatsApp
2. At bottom right tap on Settings
3. Tap on Notifications
4. Configure your settings to your liking.

Your iPhone also has settings for Notifications. To access these, go back to your Home screen and go to Settings > Notifications. Here you can configure settings as a whole and also by individual apps.

What you're wanting to do is essentially the opposite of this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325672/168832), so it may be useful for you to read that as well.